From which branch is the Jenkinsfile loaded
I have made some changes on my Jenkinsfile and I want to test the new Jenkins pipeline before delivery.
I did commit my changes on a feature branch but when I run the Jenkins pipeline it is definetely not running the version commited on my feature branch.
See the logs below:
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://bitbucket-xxx.y.zzz/myrepo/myfolder/my-api.git 
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
....

Logs do not show which branch is checked out.

Do you think the Jenkinsfile is the one on Master branch ?
How can I test the pipeline without merging my feature branch on Master ?

EDIT:
I added a branch specifier in the branch to build section

And it worked !
Thanks @unickq your answer led me to do this

You can get the answer from the configuration of your job. For test purposes, people usually create a copy of the existing job but configure it to take the Jenkinsfile from their branch.

@MaratC thanks for this comment but it is more confusing than helping. Can anyone please answer with a step by step explanation ?

Jenkinsfile loaded from master/main branch by default.
To test it you need to change Branches to build in job configuration section. Or manually set the pipeline script there.
